# Why mail sent from one Gmail in bulk to Receivers Gmail goes in Spam?

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, email-spam, bulk-mail

I have a domain with http://www.myacademicproject.com for Final Year IT Students / Internship students to whom I am sending the mail.

I have a gmail account with `myacademicprojectweb@gmail.com` from where I send mails to all my friends and the students who inquired for Final Year Project. When I send mail to all email id's the mail goes to spam folder of gmail of receipient. I have also changed the Display Name from `Shekhar Shete` to `MyAcademicProject.com`.

Any Idea to avoid as spam?

Help Appreciated!

Comment: This is not a programming related question. Try getting some help with google. There will be a lot of forums which would help!

Answer (score 0):

Verifying guidelines for [Google Bulk Senders](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=81126) may help. Further, creating [mail-merge with gmail and google-docs](http://www.labnol.org/software/mail-merge-with-gmail/13289/) shall be useful.